# putting a space between the 3rd and 4th characters of postal code in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a df (data frame) in Python with with a postal_code variable that has Canadian  postal codes. All the postal codes are collected in a row such as k1b6j2. But , for me to use the the 'pgeocode' package i need the postal code in a standard form which is like k1b 6j2 (there must be a space between the 3rd and 4th character)

So, is there a way to replace all the postal codes with the modified ones in the df?

Many Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Removed geocoding and postal_code tags as this question is strictly pandas and python related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply redefine your column in the format you are expecting:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4],'postal_code':['k1b6j2','k1b6j3','k1b6j4','k1b6j5']}) ##Example dataset

   ID postal_code
0   1      k1b6j2
1   2      k1b6j3
2   3      k1b6j4
3   4      k1b6j5
```

Redefine the `postal_code` column in the format you desire:

```
df['postal_code'] = df['postal_code'].astype(str)
df['postal_code'] = [(x[:3]+" "+x[3:]) for x in df['postal_code']]
```

Output:

```
   ID postal_code
0   1     k1b 6j2
1   2     k1b 6j3
2   3     k1b 6j4
3   4     k1b 6j5
```

Finally compared to some other methods in a 100k length dataframe:

```
df['postal_code'] = [(x[:3]+" "+x[3:]) for x in df['postal_code']] 
First method time:  0.08260965347290039
df['postal_code'] = df["postal_code"].str[:3] + " " + df["postal_code"].str[3:]
Second method time:  0.112518310546875
```

Comment: Thanks, I got an error: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable. The Postal_code variable is an object in the data frame, I assume that may cause the issue. Thanks for sharing your ideas

Comment: Check the edit please. You must have some `NaN` or numeric values if that's the error you are getting.

Comment: It workd, thanks so much. I ran print (cerbdata['POSTAL_CODE'].isnull().sum()) and I have no missing values in postal_code. So, what did the  astype(str) do to the data frame? Much appreciated

Comment: Is basically forces all values to be converted to strings, therefore you can apply string slicing methods easier. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I added some comparison so you can also have efficiency.

Comment: So, I am doing some task in this project. should I label you to notify you ? or would you prefer any other method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215202/discussion-between-celius-stingher-and-benn).

Answer (score 2):

In pandas, you can use "apply" to achive your require.

```
df['postal_code'] = df['postal_code'].apply(lambda x:x[:3]+' '+x[-3:])
```

Comment: Worked really well for me to go from an 6 character postalcode to 4 characters thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the [pandas string support](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html) that has a bunch of nice methods to work on strings such as direct slicing of string columns:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"index": range(10), "code": ["k1b6j2"]*10})
>>> df["postal_code"] = df["code"].str[:3] + " " + df["code"].str[3:]
>>> df
   index    code postal_code
0      0  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
1      1  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
2      2  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
3      3  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
4      4  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
5      5  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
6      6  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
7      7  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
8      8  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
9      9  k1b6j2     k1b 6j2
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to all postal codes in the df:

```
code_with_space = code_without_space[:3] + " " + code_without_space[3:]
```

Comment: This will fail if applied as a column in the dataframe because you are slicing the series, not the individuals values. You should use `code_without_space.str[:3]` in any case.

Comment: Or alternatively with an f_string : 
`new_code =  f'{code.str[:3]} {code.str[3:]}'`

Comment: From python 3.6 onwards sure :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
pcode = 'k1b6j2'
pcode = pcode[:3] + ' ' + pcode[3:]
```